# Efficiently walking through pandas dataframe index

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy.random import randn

oldn = pd.DataFrame(randn(10, 4), columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
```

I want to make a new DataFrame that is 0..9 rows long, and has one column "avg", whose value for row N =  average(old[N]['A'], old[N]['B']..old[N]['D'])

I'm not very familiar with pandas, so all my ideas how to do this are gross for- loops and things.  What is the efficient way to create and populate the new table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call [`mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html#pandas.DataFrame.mean) on your df and pass param `axis=1` to calculate the mean row-wise, you can then pass this as data to the `DataFrame` ctor:

```
In [128]:

new_df = pd.DataFrame(data = oldn.mean(axis=1), columns=['avg'])
new_df
Out[128]:
        avg
0  0.541550
1  0.525518
2 -0.492634
3  0.163784
4  0.012363
5  0.514676
6 -0.468888
7  0.334473
8  0.669139
9  0.736748
```

Comment: Thanks. i ended up using a variation of this, passing it a dict with several columns of descriptive stats.       setupDict = {'mean': oiDM.mean(axis=1), 'upper': (oiDM.std(axis=1)+oiDM.mean(axis=1)), 'lower': (-oiDM.std(axis=1)+oiDM.mean(axis=1))}
    chartDM = pd.DataFrame(data = setupDict)

Answer (score 0):

If you want average for specific columns use the following. Else you can use the answer provided by @EdChum

```
oldn['Avg'] = oldn.apply(lambda v: ((v['A']+v['B']+v['C']+v['D']) / 4.), axis=1)
```

or

```
old['Avg'] = oldn.apply(lambda v: ((v[['A','B','C','D']]).sum() / 4.), axis=1)
print oldn
         A         B         C         D       Avg
0 -0.201468 -0.832845  0.100299  0.044853 -0.222290
1  1.510688 -0.955329  0.239836  0.767431  0.390657
2  0.780910  0.335267  0.423232 -0.678401  0.215252
3  0.780518  2.876386 -0.797032 -0.523407  0.584116
4  0.438313 -1.952162  0.909568 -0.465147 -0.267357
5  0.145152 -0.836300  0.352706 -0.794815 -0.283314
6 -0.375432 -1.354249  0.920052 -1.002142 -0.452943
7  0.663149 -0.064227  0.321164  0.779981  0.425017
8 -1.279022 -2.206743  0.534943  0.794929 -0.538973
9 -0.339976  0.636516 -0.530445 -0.832413 -0.266579
```